# How do I set a time in the future using the time package in Golang

Tags: go, time

I wish to set a time in the future using Go, currently my code only sets the time in the present moment (time.now()) I would like to set a time 2 days after today (18/10/2021)

Here is my code

```
someTimeInTheFuture = time.now();
```

I would like to set "someTimeInTheFuture" to 2 days after today. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you want this :`time.Now().AddDate(0,0,2)` ?  https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.17.2#Time.AddDate

Answer (score 3):

And more flexible: `time.Now().Add(48 * time.Hour)`
https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.17.2#Time.Add

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).